# Javascript factory functions without this, new or prototype

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, prototype, instantiation

I use more and more often this weird (at least for me) approach and I'm starting to like it but, at the same time, I'm not sure if there isn't something horribly wrong in a context of the bigger picture.

Simplified example:

```
function createCat(initName) {
  let name = initName;
  const getName = () => name;
  function setName(newName) {
    name = newName;
  }
  function meow() {
    console.log("MEOW");
  }
  return {
    meow,
    setName,
    getName
  };
}

function createSuperCat(name) {
  const proto = createCat(name);
  const getName = () =>
    `Super secret! But hey - they used to call himself ${name}`;
  const getSecretName = () => proto.getName();
  function bark() {
    console.log("WHOOF");
  }
  return { ...proto, bark, getName, getSecretName };
}

const someCat = createCat("Hugo");
const someSuperCat = createSuperCat("Fluffy");

// someCat
console.log(someCat.getName()); // Hugo
someCat.setName("Tom");
console.log(someCat.getName()); // Tom
someCat.meow(); // MEOW

// someSuperCat
console.log(someSuperCat.getName()); // Super secret! But hey - they used to call him Fluffy
console.log(someSuperCat.getSecretName()); // Fluffy
someSuperCat.setName("Mittens");
console.log(someSuperCat.getSecretName()); // Mittens
console.log(someSuperCat.getName()); // Super secret! But hey - they used to call him Fluffy
someSuperCat.meow(); // MEOW
someSuperCat.bark(); // WHOOF
```

I'm aware that there's not such thing as the only correct way and if something works it's a valid solution.

But still - I'm just wondering...do you see any caveats in this approach?

So far it seems it can do all the fancy things like inherit, extend or override inherited method and you can omit the old-time-y OOP's *this*, you don't have to instantiate a standard factory function with *new* keyword, there's no *prototype* pattern (well, actually there kinda is - and since it's Javascript, there always will be), there aren't any *class*es or other syntactic sugar.

I may be wrong. I'm not a real programmer or something so I would appreciate an input from someone experienced because I'm probably missing something what can cause some discomfort later on.

Comment: Try posting this question to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What’s the point of it? The biggest caveat is that if anybody else ever has to work with your code they’ll have to deal with the cognitive overhead of having to figure out what’s going on and why. Second is that you’re doing manually what’s already provided by JS.

Comment: This is known as parasitical inheritance. Quite a standard approach, apart maybe from the mutation of the local `name` variable without changing the `.name` property. It's common in functional programming though.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you. I'll try to find out more about that. I realized that I shouldn't expose `name`in return from base function. Do you think that if I use something like `return Object.freeze({ // stuff I want to expose from a function })` that it can solve some dangerous mutability issues? Sorry, if it's a silly question. I'm just curious and since I occasionally use React which got rid off classes I would like to move towards some more modern functional approach. This is just a naive example.

Comment: @DaveNewton Well, my example is just silly but there actually is the point of it - the messy *this*. It's explained here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/removing-javascripts-this-keyword-makes-it-a-better-language-here-s-why-db28060cc086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern is fine, as long as you realise the loss of features like:

- `instanceof` operator,
- `Object.getPrototypeOf`,
- `prototype` and `constructor` properties
- No copy of functions as you would have them on the prototype

There seems to also be an impact on performance.

Here is a comparison with an OOP implementation in modern syntax. Note that it uses private fields, which at the time of writing is not supported in all engines, notably not in FireFox. But for instance in Chrome it runs fine:

```js
// Parasitic implementation
function createCat(initName) {
  let name = initName;
  const getName = () => name;
  function setName(newName) {
    name = newName;
  }
  function meow() {
    return "MEOW";
  }
  return {
    meow,
    setName,
    getName
  };
}

function createSuperCat(name) {
  const proto = createCat(name);
  const getName = () =>
    `Super secret! But hey - they used to call himself ${name}`;
  const getSecretName = () => proto.getName();
  function bark() {
    return "WHOOF";
  }
  return { ...proto, bark, getName, getSecretName };
}

// OOP implementation
class Cat {
    #name
    constructor(initName) {
        this.#name = initName;
    }
    get name() { 
        return this.#name; 
    }
    set name(newName) {
        this.#name = newName;
    }
    meow() {
        return "MEOW";
    }
}

class SuperCat extends Cat {
    #name
    constructor(initName) {
        super(initName);
        this.#name = initName;
    }
    get name() {
        return `Super secret! But hey - they used to call himself ${super.name}`;
    }
    set name(newName) {
        this.#name = newName;
    }
    get secretName() {
        return this.#name;
    }
    bark() {
        return "WHOOF";
    }
}

function testParasitic() {
    // First produce the output as by OP
    let output = [];
    const someCat = createCat("Hugo");
    const someSuperCat = createSuperCat("Fluffy");

    // someCat
    output.push(someCat.getName()); // Hugo
    someCat.setName("Tom");
    output.push(someCat.getName()); // Tom
    output.push(someCat.meow()); // MEOW

    // someSuperCat
    output.push(someSuperCat.getName()); // Super secret! But hey - they used to call him Fluffy
    output.push(someSuperCat.getSecretName()); // Fluffy
    someSuperCat.setName("Mittens");
    output.push(someSuperCat.getSecretName()); // Mittens
    output.push(someSuperCat.getName()); // Super secret! But hey - they used to call him Fluffy
    output.push(someSuperCat.meow()); // MEOW
    output.push(someSuperCat.bark()); // WHOOF
    console.log(output.join(", "));

    // Then run a performance test:
    let start = performance.now();
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        const someCat = createCat("Hugo");
        someCat.setName("Tom");
        someCat.getName(); // Tom
        someCat.meow(); // MEOW
        for (let j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            const someSuperCat = createSuperCat("Fluffy");
            someSuperCat.setName("Mittens");
            someSuperCat.getSecretName();
            someSuperCat.getName();
            someSuperCat.meow();
            someSuperCat.bark();
        }
    }
    return performance.now() - start;
}

function testOOP() {
    // First produce the output as by OP
    let output = [];
    const someCat = new Cat("Hugo");
    const someSuperCat = new SuperCat("Fluffy");

    // someCat
    output.push(someCat.name); // Hugo
    someCat.name = "Tom";
    output.push(someCat.name); // Tom
    output.push(someCat.meow()); // MEOW

    // someSuperCat
    output.push(someSuperCat.name); // Super secret! But hey - they used to call him Fluffy
    output.push(someSuperCat.secretName); // Fluffy
    someSuperCat.name = "Mittens";
    output.push(someSuperCat.secretName); // Mittens
    output.push(someSuperCat.name); // Super secret! But hey - they used to call him Fluffy
    output.push(someSuperCat.meow()); // MEOW
    output.push(someSuperCat.bark()); // WHOOF
    console.log(output.join(", "));

    // Then run a performance test:
    let start = performance.now();
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        const someCat = new Cat("Hugo");
        someCat.name = "Tom";
        someCat.name;
        someCat.meow();
        for (let j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            const someSuperCat = new SuperCat("Fluffy");
            someSuperCat.name = "Mittens";
            someSuperCat.secretName;
            someSuperCat.name;
            someSuperCat.meow();
            someSuperCat.bark();
        }
    }
    return performance.now() - start;
}

let dur1 = testParasitic();
let dur2 = testOOP();

console.log("duration parasitic test", Math.round(dur1));
console.log("duration OOP test", Math.round(dur2));
```

Comment: thank you very much for your insightful response! i really appreciate your effort. i have to admit that i didn't even know that private fields are coming to js. right now, i'm using this so called parasitic approach to write an audio engine based on webaudio api. its usage is pretty straightforward. something along the lines of  `const ctx = createAudio(); ctx.startOsc(node)` etc...it seems that in my case it shouldn't be a problem since i instantiate it just once and then i just use a few closures exposed to an user. so i can only rewrite parts which will be "instantiated" frequently, right?

Comment: Yes, the performance side of the comparison is irrelevant if you're just creating one or even a few instances.

Answer (score 1):

So one of the biggest caveats to this approach is firstly, adding unecessary complexity to your code, since JS already has solutions to what you're doing so you're not really achieving anything by doing it this way. But also this approach will be a a lot more inefficient and waste memory as you increase the amount of objects. One benefit of prototypical inheritance and the `this` keyword is that all you functions can be stored within a single object reference

Your approach redefines all functions for each object. So every time you create a new `cat` object you are redefining all your generic functions. Which are being stored in memory for each object.

Even if you want to avoid classes and using `new`, it would be better to take advantage of prototypical inheritance and the `this` keyword.

I rewrote your code as such:

```js
const catProto = {
  getName: function () {
    return this.name;
  },
  setName: function (newName) {
    this.name = newName;
  },
  meow: function () {
    console.log("MEOW");
  },
};

function createCat(name) {
  const cat = Object.create(catProto);
  cat.name = name;
  return cat;
}

function createSuperCat(name) {
  const cat = createCat(name);
  cat.getName = () => `Super secret...`;
  cat.getSecretName = catProto.getName;
  cat.bark = () => console.log("WHOOF");
  return cat;
}

const someCat = createCat("Hugo");
const someSuperCat = createSuperCat("Fluffy");

// someCat
console.log(someCat.getName()); // Hugo
someCat.setName("Tom");
console.log(someCat.getName()); // Tom
someCat.meow(); // MEOW

// someSuperCat
console.log(someSuperCat.getName()); // Super secret! But hey - they used to call him Fluffy
console.log(someSuperCat.getSecretName()); // Fluffy
someSuperCat.setName("Mittens");
console.log(someSuperCat.getSecretName()); // Mittens
console.log(someSuperCat.getName()); // Super secret! But hey - they used to call him Fluffy
someSuperCat.meow(); // MEOW
someSuperCat.bark(); // WHOOF
```